# Does interacting with variables in the following method cause any performance decline 

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Ok, so I have a reference to a `div` stored in a variable, lets called it `div_var`.

Now I want to do something to it; I can reference it in both the following ways;

```
div_var.animate()......
$(div_var).animate().....
```

The first way is obviously easier, the only problem is my code editor (Komodo) won't offer any code hinting/code completion for it. The second way gives me full code hinting but I don't know if I'm taking a performance hit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Felix Kling was correct, it is slower. I created a simple test

**HTML**

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="width: 600px;">
    <p class="t1-start">1</p>
    <p class="t2-start">1</p>
</body>

</html>
```

**JS (test.js)**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var num = $('.t1-start')
var num2 = $('.t2-start')

firstCount()    

function firstCount(){
    var time = new Date()
    var start = time.getTime()

    for (var i=0; i < 10000; i++) {
        $(num).append(' 1');
    }
    var time2 = new Date()
    var end = time2.getTime()
    var leng = end - start;
    var leng_string = '<h1>'+leng+'</h1>'
    $(num).replaceWith(leng_string)

    secondCount()
}

function secondCount(){
    var time = new Date()
    var start = time.getTime()

    for (var i=0; i < 10000; i++) {
        num2.append(' 1');
    }
    var time2 = new Date()
    var end = time2.getTime()
    var leng = end - start;
    var leng_string = '<h1>'+leng+'</h1>'
    $(num2).replaceWith(leng_string)
}

})
```

the first loop is consistently about 15-20% slower.

Answer (score -1):

If `div_var` is already a jQuery object, then passing it to jQuery again is superfluous.

Whether it has influence on the performance depends on your application. Fact is, it is an additional, unnecessary function call.

Comment: @downvoter: Please explain. Otherwise I don't know where I'm wrong or what I should improve. Thank you!

Comment: I hate people who down vote like this without any explaination.

Comment: div_var may or may not be a jquery object. Even if it was a jquery object it would still be stored in a variable as I'd be passing that variable from the event listener to a handler. For example;
    $('.button').click(function(){
    doStuff($(this)); 
    })


    function doStuff(div_var){
    //this is where I'd be using either
    // div_var or $(div_var)
    }

Comment: @geoken: Then I don't understand your question. To me it looked like `div_var` is a jQuery object and you wanted to know whether passing it again to jQuery will have an impact on the performance. The reason for passing it again seemed to be getting code completion from the IDE. Please be more clear about what you want to know. Whether you should pass it as `doStuff(this)` or `doStuff($(this))` and then call `div_var...` or `$(div_var)...` is another question. So, what do you actually want to know?

Comment: The doStuff() isn't really relevant to my question. I just wanted to know if there was a performance hit when calling $(div_var).. instead of div_var..

Comment: @geoken: Then I think I answered the question: *Whether it has influence on the performance depends on your application. Fact is, it is an additional, unnecessary function call.* You could remove the *"unnecessary"*. Obviously, a function call takes more time than doing no function call. And still, I wonder why you asked this. If `div_var` is *not* a jQuery object, you have to pass it to jQuery. If it is, you don't have to, if you don't know, then, again,  you have to. So either you have to call `$(div_var)` or not. You don't have a choice here.

Comment: div_var is a jQuery object but it works whether I use $(div_var).animate() or div_var.animate(). Maybe in the background it's doing the same thing?

Comment: @geoken: When you pass a jQuery object to jQuery again, then it will basically take the contents and create a new jQuery object. This comes at the cost of an additional function call. That is what I meant: If you know that `div_var` is a jQuery object, then you should **not** pass it again to the jQuery, as it is unnecessary. I have the feeling I actually understood your question from the beginning. Now is the question whether you understood my answer or not?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I just did a simple test with 10k iterations. $(var) was consistently about 15% slower than var. 

I wish I could upvote you but my rep is too low.